# Unable to find match between the canonical context path and the URI presented by the user agent

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I am running a spring boot application in my local system deployed in tomcat container. Everything is working fine. But when the same code is deployed to the server, it is showing exception for an URL -

For Example, if the Project context path is xyz -

http://localhost:8080/xyz;id/ is not giving any error but the same in the server (https://server/xyz;id/) is throwing 500 error as follows -

I have also tried writing a controller to handle the "/error" path as the error is routing through ErrorPageFilter.java. But it's of no use.

Exception Stacktrace -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find match between the canonical context path [/httpsportal] and the URI presented by the user agent [/httpsportal;id/]
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getContextPath(Request.java:1958)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getContextPath(RequestFacade.java:783)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:166)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
```

Expected to route back to "/xyz" or redirect to "/error" page. But none are happening.

*Note that /xyz;id is converting as /xyz but keeping a slash at the last i.e /xyz;id/ is throwing an error (in server).*

Comment: Are you expecting that `;id` to be a [path parameter](https://www.jtmelton.com/2011/02/02/beware-the-http-path-parameter/)?

Comment: NO mate, The URL I mentioned it is a part of security testing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue found with the server tomcat version v8.0.20

Once upgraded the tomcat version to some higher one, the issue is not reproducible.